# What is the Windows equivalent of this Linux command to create a virtual environment with Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, environment

I am new to using the Terminal and in my homework assigment i have to create a virtual environment for the class with Python = 3.6.1 running this:

```
    conda create -n cs7643 python=3.6.1 anaconda
    conda activate cs7643
```

I have windows and this doesn't work.

Does anyone know the equivalent? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the `conda` command you need to have anaconda installed on the machine. Check to make sure you have anaconda installed. Do you see [image: Anaconda Terminal] this on Windows?

See the getting started if you have issues.
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

To create the environment there are 2 ways, one is to use the GUI and second is to use the terminal/command line.

See the following for creating the workspace.
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: Another command would be ```conda env create -f environment.yml``` but you also will need the environment.yaml with all your dependencies listed